# Best learning resources for hybrid mobile app development

Tags: android, ios, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

What are the good learning resources for hybrid mobile application development for both iOs and android devices?

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of video tutorials about jQuery Mobile ranging from simple ones to really advanced ones.

First take a look at this one : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6Y4a0hA8tI, you are not going to see many examples there but it is one hour of a comprehensive walk through of jQuery Mobile and its functionalities. Trust me this is a first thing you would want to watch.

Second one is **pineheadtv** tutorial list: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AyZbIaYF_OU&list=PL09E541FDC1A3E551. This one will walk you through a lot of working examples.

Also take a look at a few of my articles:

- **[jQuery document ready vs jQuery Mobile page events](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/)**
- **[jQuery Mobile and how to enhance the markup of dynamically added content](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**

Those 2 links will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Hi Thanks, i visited those pages those really gave me a glimpse on how Jquery mobile differs from jquery that we use in web pages...If u know any free video source other than google that'd be great bcuz youtube access is blocked by proxy server...

Answer (score 0):

This is the site you want! I ♥ it!

http://www.lynda.com/

Detailed videos and good authors. iPad app is crap, but for the most part the content is great!